# Play! Framework enhancement process

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I've been studying a Play! Framework module and looking to extend it, add some features. I  found a class that extends from Enhancer (play.classloading.enhancers.Enhancer) and couldn't figure out why Play! adopted this model.

Why loading classes and make their community code extensions like this? I've read their very simple explanation oh why they do that and I felt like being treated as a grandmother hehe: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/main#Classenhancement

But it didn't helped as I wanted to. Why can't I just code the class my users will extend with the intended functionality? In cases that they will have to reload classes given some dynamic or special functionality, ok, but my plugin code is static by nature.

Does anyone know why they do it and if I'm required to do it? (going to test it while waiting for answers!)

Answer (score 1):

Bytecode enhancement is a tool play! used to extend Java language, and inject some "magic" logic into application's code. One example is controller's render method enhancement which enable you to write the following code:

```
public static void myAction() {
   String foo = "...";
   int bar = "...";
   render(foo, bar);
}
```

instead of

```
public static void myAction() {
   String foo = "...";
   int bar = "...";
   renderArgs.put("foo", foo);
   renderArgs.put("bar", bar);
   render();
}
```

What happened is a `LocalVariableEnhancer` will enhance the `myAction` method and generate a map from variable name to variable. And inside `render` method, it will check that map and put the variables into renderArgs automatically for you.

There are other cases like `get/set` method generation and JPA model's static factory methods etc. Modules like `play-morphia` also use bytecode enhancer heavily. The goal is to provide an ultimate application developer experience that you cannot deliver within pure Java language framework, say inheritance, interface etc.

Comment: That I had already got, but it should be used by every plugin or it is over used in some cases?

Comment: No. Not all plugin needs to override the `PlayPlugin.enhance` method, and thus no all plugin needs a subclass of `Enhancer`.